# Finding memory leak at certain point of runtime

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks

I need to find out what objects are not deleted between application states, here is code example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class MyClass {
public:
    int myNum;
};

std::vector<MyClass *> firstStateClasses;
std::map<int, MyClass *> stateClasses;

void MakeFirstState()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        MyClass* firstClass = new MyClass();
        firstStateClasses.push_back(firstClass);
    }
}

void DeleteFirstState()
{
    for (auto p : firstStateClasses)
    {
        delete p;
    }
    firstStateClasses.clear();
}

void MakeState(int state)
{
    MyClass* randomClass = new MyClass();

    stateClasses.insert(std::make_pair(state, randomClass));
}

void DeleteState(int state)
{
    auto itr = stateClasses.find(state);
    if (itr != stateClasses.end())
    {
        delete itr->second;
        stateClasses.erase(itr);
    }
}

int main()
{
    MakeFirstState();
    MakeState(0);
    //Leak is here, state wasnt deleted.
    MakeState(1);
    //I need to know here objects that were made only in MakeState(0) and not deleted.
    DeleteState(1);
    MakeState(2);
    DeleteState(2);
    DeleteFirstState();
}
```

I was trying to use Visual Studio memory heap profiling, but it isnt very usefull since i cant single out only objects that were made in MakeState(0) and were not deleted after MakeState(1).

Comment: why use `new` and `delete` in the first place? Rule of thumb: When your code has a `new` it has a leak.

Comment: `std::vector<MyClass *> firstStateClasses;` should be `std::vector<MyClass> firstStateClasses;`.

Comment: you can try valgrind

Comment: if you used `shared_ptr`/`unique_ptr` you wouldn't have to worry about it, removing an item from the map would automatically delete it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Its a 20+ years old software with thousands lines of code, i know smart pointers are better, but i cant work on refactoring it yet.

Comment: If the question is only about automatic memory leaks identification (because leaks in your code are obvious without using any tools), forget about Microsoft tools, they are <to put it mildly> "not the best". Just run your code with [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) and you will see all the leaks.

Comment: when there is a leak then eventually you will need to fix it, and employing RAII one way or the other is the way to go. You could fix it already before detecting the leaks. Though, if thats your question then that is your question. You should mention that fixing the code is not an option for now, because thats the obvious solution

Comment: @pptaszni Forgot to mention it runs on windows only, so unfortunately cant use valgrind.

Comment: @pptaszni not sure valgrind will help, it'll tell you something was leaked and it'll say when it was allocated but I'm not sure that it'll tell you when it was leaked (i.e when the last reference to it was lost)?

Comment: isnt it the case that the objects that are not deleted are exactly thsose that are still present in the vector?

Comment: No, objects that are not deleted will be present in `map` untill application exits.

Comment: _"When your code has a `new` it has a leak"_ Wrong, absolutely wrong. Otherwise every code depending on the standard library would have a leak. RAII just hides the use of `new`, it doesn't remove it. And adds more robustness for specific cases of course (when exceptions are thrown for example)

Comment: as @4630 says, you don't seem to delete anything at the first commented point

Comment: "No, objects that are not deleted will be present in map untill application exits." but they are removed from the vector. In the vector are only thsoe that are not deleted yet and those that are deleted are not in the vector. I dont understand what more you need

Comment: @NeilButterworth Thats right, but in the example i know which objects are not deleted, in my application i only know they are leaking between states and i need to know what are they.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Vector contains different objects, i just need to know what objects made in MakeState(0) were not deleted after MakeState(1) was called.

Comment: ok sorry, they are in the map not in the vector, but I still do not see why it isnt sufficient to look in the map what objects are there for key `0` and then you know they were made in `MakeState(0)` and not deleted yet

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yeah, i wish it was that easy, unfortunately, objects in map have random key for each state, and since there are thousands of them (and in different containers, classes, etc.), doing it manually is pretty much impossible. I thought there might be some tool that would snapshot objects made in MakeState(0) and show everything that still exists after MakeState(1).

Comment: they arent random, neither are there thousands. If your actual issue is different from the code you posted you should edit and clarify

Comment: My needs are specifically explained in code, otherwise i would need to post whole solution with multiple projects.

Comment: in the code you posted they key in the map is fully known. When in your real code they are random, why not make them random in the simplified example too?

Comment: Because its simplified.

Comment: making something random into not random and explaining that it actually is random is not "simplified". Don't get me wrong, its difficult to prepare good exampels and to write queistons. But I do not see the issue in the code you did post. All the information is right there in the map and vector. On the other hand, if the code does not actually matter that much, but the question is about a tool to be used, thats offtopic unfortunately.

Comment: it's not simplified, it's completely different

Comment: I thought you can create multiple heap snapshots with Visual Studio, and compare them.

Comment: Also, with this code, I wonder if your problem isn't actually a situation like `MakeState(1); MakeState(1); DeleteState(1); DeleteState(1);`, because if the same state is entered again, the previous value is not deleted.